# No WiFi Adapter found Ubuntu 18.04 | Dell

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, network-interface, pci

I have dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and it's been quite a time. But, recently I can't seem to connect to any of the wireless networks and it's showing "No WiFi Adapter found" in the WiFi settings. I've tried many solutions but nothing seems to work. Furthermore, I'd like to add that even the `lshw` command doesn't display any information about my wireless interface.
Given below is the output of `lshw` and `rfkill` command.

```
sudo rfkill list   
  0:  hci0: Bluetooth  
  Soft blocked: no  
  Hard blocked: no
```

.

```
sudo lshw -c network
< outputs nothing >
```

.

```
sudo lshw -short
H/W path       Device       Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         Inspiron 7559 (0706)
/0                          bus            0H0CC0
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/30                       memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/31                       memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/32                       memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/33                       memory         6MiB L3 cache
/0/34                       processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.6
/0/35                       memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/35/0                     memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz
/0/35/1                     memory         DIMM LPDDR4 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6
/0/100                      bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Co
/0/100/1                    bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Co
/0/100/1.1                  bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Co
/0/100/1.1/0                display        GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
/0/100/2                    display        HD Graphics 530
/0/100/4                    generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Co
/0/100/14                   bus            100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family
/0/100/14/0    usb1         bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/2               communication  OnePlus
/0/100/14/0/3               input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/4               multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/0/5               communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/6               input          Atmel maXTouch Digitizer
/0/100/14/1    usb2         bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                 generic        100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family
/0/100/15                   generic        100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family
/0/100/16                   communication  100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family
/0/100/17                   storage        HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [
/0/100/1c                   bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family
/0/100/1c.6                 bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family
/0/100/1c.6/0               generic        RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1f                   bridge         HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f.2                 memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                 multimedia     100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family
/0/100/1f.4                 bus            100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family
/0/1           scsi1        storage        
/0/1/0.0.0     /dev/sda     disk           1TB TOSHIBA MQ02ABD1
/0/1/0.0.0/1   /dev/sda1    volume         499MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2    volume         127MiB reserved partition
/0/1/0.0.0/3   /dev/sda3    volume         734GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4   /dev/sda4    volume         861MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/5   /dev/sda5    volume         195GiB EXT4 volume
/1                          power          Battery Name
/2                          power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
/3             enp0s20f0u2  network        Ethernet interface
```

Edit: Even Windows can't detect the wireless interface.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 contains a relatively old Linux kernel. Try a newer version of Ubuntu or install kernel 5.8.3 manually.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have already upgraded my kernel to 'Linux 5.4.0-42-generic'.

Comment: And the current version is 5.8.3. 5.4.0 is a year old kernel. Also, if your module is contains a RF chip from Realtek you'll most likely have to install out of the tree drivers.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks for the help. I upgraded my kernel, reinstalled my drivers and I could see my wireless interface again!

Answer (score 0):

> Even Windows can't detect the wireless interface.

It's probably hardware related. The adapter is probably the problem.

Try to access the card (it's probably a small addon card) - often easy to do...
Try to dismount-remount the card. Then reboot and test.

If nothing new, try to change the card with a working one. Then reboot and test. Look for [informations on card format](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/mini-pci-mini-pci-e-mini-pci-e-half-height-guide-laptop-wifi-cards). There is basically three kind of cards : (old) mini-PCI, mini-PCIe(full or half height) or (new) M2.

If nothing new, the problem is probably further... try a USB WiFi adapter, but I'll expect other hardware problems !

Greetings